# Kafka: Consume partition with manual batching - Messages are being skipped

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka, librdkafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am using [Confluent Kafka .NET](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) to create a consumer for a partitioned topic.

As Confluent Kafka .NET does not support consuming in batches, I built a function that consumes messages until the batch size is reached. The idea of this function is to build batches with messages from the same partition only, that is why I stop building the batch once I consume a result that has a different partition and return whatever number of messages I was able to consume up to that point.

**Goal or Objective:** I want to be able to process the messages I returned in the batch, and commit the offsets for those messages only. i.e:

| Message Consumed From Partition | Offset | Stored in Batch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Yes |
| 0 | 1 | Yes |
| 2 | 0 | No |

From the table above I would like to process both messages I got from partition 0. Message from partition 2 would be ignored and (hopefully) PICKED UP LATER in another call to **ConsumeBatch**.

To commit I simply call the synchronous `Commit` function passing the offset of the latest message I processed as parameter. In this case I would pass the offset of the second message of the batch shown in the table above (Partition 0 - Offset 1).

**ISSUE:**

The problem is that for some reason, when I build a batch like the one shown above, the messages I decide not to process because of validations are being ignored forever. i.e: Message 0 of partition 2 will never be picked up by the consumer again.

As you can see in the consumer configuration below, I have set both **EnableAutoCommit** and **EnableAutoOffsetStore** as false. I think this would be enough for the consumer to not do anything with the offsets and be able to pick up ignored messages in another `Consume` call, but it isn't. The offset is somehow increasing up to the latest consumed message for each partition, regardless of my configuration.

Can anybody give me some light on what am I missing here to achieve the desired behavior if possible?

**Simplified version of the function to build the batch:**

```
public IEnumerable<ConsumeResult<string, string>> ConsumeBatch(int batchSize)
{
    List<ConsumeResult<string, string>> consumedMessages = new List<ConsumeResult<string, string>>();

    int latestPartition = -1; // The partition from where we consumed the last message

    for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
    {
        var result = _consumer.Consume(100);
        
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (latestPartition == -1 || result.Partition.Value == latestPartition)
            {
                consumedMessages.Add(result);
                latestPartition = result.Partition.Value;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    return consumedMessages;
}
```

**ConsumerConfig used to instantiate my consumer client:**

```
_consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = _bootstrapServers,
            EnableAutoCommit = false,
            AutoCommitIntervalMs = 0,
            GroupId = "WorkerConsumers",
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
            EnableAutoOffsetStore = false,
        };
```

***Additional Information:***
This is being tested with:

- 1 topic with 6 partitions and replication factor of 2
- 3 brokers
- 1 single-threaded consumer client that belongs to a consumer group
- Local environment with wsl2 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was to use the `Seek` function to reset the partition's offset to a specific position so that the ignored message could be picked up again as part of another batch.

**In the same function above:**

```
public IEnumerable<ConsumeResult<string, string>> ConsumeBatch(int batchSize)
{
    List<ConsumeResult<string, string>> consumedMessages = new List<ConsumeResult<string, string>>();

    int latestPartition = -1; // The partition from where we consumed the last message

    for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
    {
        var result = _consumer.Consume(100);
    
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (latestPartition == -1 || result.Partition.Value == latestPartition)
            {
                consumedMessages.Add(result);
                latestPartition = result.Partition.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                // This call will guarantee that this message that will not be included in the current batch, will be included in another batch later
                _consumer.Seek(result.TopicPartitionOffset); // IMPORTANT LINE!!!!!!!
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    return consumedMessages;
}
```

I think in general, if you want to consume a message without altering the offsets in any way (kinda peeking the topic partition), you can call `Consume` and then use `Seek(result.TopicPartitionOffset)` to set the offset of that topic partition back to where it was before consuming the message.